# Why does Android Studio insist on certain package names?

Tags: android, android-studio

I chose a package name for my project when I ran the project wizard, it is "ss.myPkg".  At the top of every new java file I create I also put "package ss.myPkg".

There are some demons that every once in a while lead to the error msg "Error: Activity class {com.companyName.pcName.myPkg/ss.myPkg.MainActivity} does not exist.".  It compiles fine and this error only occurs when I attempt to run as Debug on my physical Android device through ADB.  Worked fine all day yesterday and now today it flopped.  "com.companyName.pcName.myPkg" is the default that would be used by the project when I create a new project.  But I at time of creating the project I chose "ss.myPkg".  I cannot find "com.companyName.pcName.myPkg" anywhere in my code or project settings.  The only way out of this dead end is to create an entirely new project which is a PITA.

Where in the world is this crap coming from?

Comment: Did you change it in Android Manifest?

Comment: "The only way out of this dead end is to create an entirely new project which is a PITA" -- probably not. Close the project in Android Studio. Back up the project (in case of problems following these instructions). Delete the `.iml` file, the `.idea/` directory, the `.gradle/` directory, and the `build/` directory from the project root. Delete the `.iml` file and the `build/` directory from your module (e.g., `app/`). Then, open Android Studio and choose to import the project.

Comment: Vucko - I created the project with ss.notify as the package name, so it is reflected correctly in the manifest

Comment: CommonsWare - Thanks for the tip.  It does work, though it's almost the same process as creating a new project and copying over all my source and resource files.

Comment: Well, that got me through 5 hours and now it happened again.  Clearly something is wrong in my project.  One shouldn't have to rebuild new projects every 5 hours.